# How to subset a dataframe using multiple regular expressions in variable names?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with over 500 named variables, and I want to select only the columns whose names include the strings "xyz" and "abc". The first letter is sometimes capitalized, sometimes not, so I'm using a regular expression "[Aa]bc" etc.

I have the full dataset in a dataframe called df, and I'm building a new dataframe called df2 by selecting variables out of df using grep(). I can do it one at a time and stick them together with cbind(), but I'd like to know how to do it all in one go.

I thought I could pass multiple conditions to grep(), but seem to be getting stuck here.

With a really simplified example:

```
df <- data.frame(abc=1:3, def=4:6, Xyz=7:9, Abc=10:12, xyz=13:15)

  abc def Xyz Abc xyz
1   1   4   7  10  13
2   2   5   8  11  14
3   3   6   9  12  15
```

I successfully got the columns I needed using two separate lines:

```
df2 <- df[,grep("[Aa]bc", names(df), value=TRUE)]
df3 <- df[,grep("[Xx]yz", names(df), value=TRUE)]
df4 <- cbind(df2, df3)
```

When I try to do all this at once using:

```
df2 <- df[,grep("[Aa]bc" | "[Xx]yz", names(df), value=TRUE)]
```

I got the following error:

> Error in "[Aa]bc" | "[Xx]yz" :    operations are possible only for
>   numeric, logical or complex types

I also tried passing the conditions to grep as a list of the strings, but it didn't work:

```
df2 <- df[,grep(c("[Aa]bc", "[Xx]yz"), names(df), value=TRUE)]
```

It only used the first list item with a warning:

> In grep(c("[Aa]bc", "[Xx]yz"), names(df), value = TRUE) :   argument
>   'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

so it only selected the columns with "[Aa]bc", and skipped "[Xx]yz".

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the regex in one string itself

```
df[,grep("[Aa]bc|[Xx]yz", names(df))]

#  abc Xyz Abc
#1   1   7  10
#2   2   8  11
#3   3   9  12
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an argument `ignore.case` which If set to `TRUE`, well, it ignores (upper/lower) case, i.e.

```
df[grepl('xyz|abc', names(df), ignore.case = TRUE)]

#   abc Xyz Abc
#1   1   7  10
#2   2   8  11
#3   3   9  12
```

Comment: Thanks! That works too. I just got hung up by not having all the regex in the same quotes.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use a "purely" RegEx way to ignore case. Otherwise, one can set `ignore.case` to `TRUE` as already shown:

```
df[grepl("(?i)[a-c]|(?i)[x-z]", names(df))]
  abc Xyz Abc
1   1   7  10
2   2   8  11
3   3   9  12
```

We can also do this with `stringi`:

```
df[stri_detect(names(df), regex = "xyz|abc",case_insensitive = TRUE)]
  abc Xyz Abc
1   1   7  10
2   2   8  11
3   3   9  12
```

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
 library(dplyr)
  library(stringi)

df %>% 
  purrr::keep(stri_detect(names(df),
                           regex = "xyz|abc",case_insensitive = TRUE))
  abc Xyz Abc
1   1   7  10
2   2   8  11
3   3   9  12
```

Comment: Why are you using capital letters in your regex (first case) if you set `ignore.case` to true? What am I missing here?

Comment: I answered before seeing OP's actual intended output. Got confused by the `cbind` so perhaps forgot to edit that out. I have removed it anyways and will just show a tidyverse approach.

Comment: Oh ok. I am a bit regex-blind so I couldn't translate that regex, hence my question if I missed something.

Comment: `grep` also have ignore.case